# How to remove all hyphens and spaces from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following code:

```sql
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, UPPER(cb.gender), cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 5);
```

I want to adjust it so that before `cb.phone (varchar2)` values are added to `dwcust`, all hyphens and spaces are removed from the strings so that they are just numeric.

For instance I want `04-1234 5254` to become `0412345254`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `regexp_replace()`

```
select regexp_replace('04-1234 5254', '[- ]', '')
from dual;
```

This would still return something that is not a number if it e.g. contains a `/`

To make sure or to remove everything that is not a number use the following:

```
select regexp_replace('04-1234 5254', '[^0-9]', '')
from dual;
```

---

Just replace `cb.phone` with `regexp_replace(cb.phone, , '[^0-9]', '')` in your SELECT list.

```sql
SELECT ...., regexp_replace(cb.phone, , '[^0-9]', ''), ....
FROM a2custbris cb
....
```

Comment: Looks like this would work for me, but I'm sorry I'm a bit of a noob, how do I incorporate this into my block? I tried but couldn't figure out what the right syntax.

Comment: @Wah.P: you use that function call instead of the direct column reference. See my edit

Answer (score 3):

[`Translate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html) can be useful:

```
translate(cb.phone, 'X- ', 'X')
```

For example,

```
select translate(' 04-1234 5254', 'X- ', 'X')
from dual
```

gives:

```
TRANSLATE('04-12345254','X-','X')
---------------------------------
0412345254                       
1 row selected.
```

About this usage, Oracle docs says:

> You cannot use an empty string for to_string to remove all characters
>   in from_string from the return value. Oracle Database interprets the
>   empty string as null, and if this function has a null argument, then
>   it returns null. To remove all characters in from_string, concatenate
>   another character to the beginning of from_string and specify this
>   character as the to_string. For example, TRANSLATE(expr,
>   'x0123456789', 'x') removes all digits from expr.